# transform the data and create histogram with facets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have 400 columns with dynamic names (t_namelist1_namelist2). There are 20 names in each namelist1 and namelist2. I have to create a histogram with facets `20 by 20`, with labels -

- along row - namelist1
- along col - namelist2

Can someone please show how to transform the data using pivot_longer() using `_` which separates the three parts `t`, `namelist1` and `namelist2`

In the sample problem, I have a tibble with 4 columns, I want to create 4 individual histograms in 2by2 facets with labels -

- along row - a and b
- along col - x and y

Thanks

```
library(tidyverse)

t_a_x <- rnorm(100)
t_b_x <- rnorm(100)
t_a_y <- rnorm(100)
t_b_y <- rnorm(100)

tbl <- tibble(t_a_x, t_a_y, t_b_x, t_b_y)


# create a histogram in 2 by 2 facets with labels - 
# along row - a and b
# along col - x and y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first chunk of code below rearranges the example data into three-column data frame, each column corresponding to either "ab", "xy", or the value ("t"); basically separating the original column name by "_". Then you can plot and facet based on "xy" and "ab".

```
# Rearrange table by separating the column names by "_" using pivot_longer()
tbl_formatted <- tbl %>% pivot_longer(everything(),
   names_to = c(".value", "ab", "xy"),
   names_sep = c("_")
     ) 

# Plot
tbl_formatted %>% ggplot(aes(x = t, y = t)) +
   geom_point() + 
   facet_wrap(facets = ab ~ xy)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic version of the plot; you can customize it with colors and more.

To get it, you need to properly rearrange your dataframe:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl <- tibble(value = c(t_a_x, t_b_x, t_a_y, t_b_y), 
              lab1 = rep(c("a", "b", "a", "b"), each = 100),  
              lab2 = rep(c("x", "x", "y", "y"), each = 100))

ggplot(tbl) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(value), binwidth = 0.5) + 
  facet_grid(lab1~lab2)
```

Comment: Thanks Leonardo, but this was a sample example. In actual case, I have to create 20 by 20 facet and it is difficult to write lab1 and lab2 for dynamic case. Can you please show a dynamic solution using pivot_longer() function